# Retrieving multivalued field elements

Tags: solr, lucene, solrj

I've multivalued field and i want to display all array elements using solrj command.

I used the command mentioned below but i'm able to retrieve only 1st element of the array.

response.getResults().get(0).getFieldValueMap().get("discussions")
Output: Creation Time - 2014-06-12 17:37:53.0

```
NOTE: "discussions" is multivalued field in solr which contains

 <arr name="discussions">
  <str>Creation Time - 2014-06-12 17:37:53.0</str>
  <str>Last modified Time - 2014-06-12 17:42:09.0</str>
  <str>Comment - posting bug from risk flows ...posting comment from risk flows ...syncing comments ...</str>
</arr>
```

Is there any solrj API used for retrieving multivalued elements or its not possible..? Please help me..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SolrJ has dedicated methods to get a Collection of values for the field instead of a single value: [`getFieldValues(<fieldname>)`](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_2_1/solr-solrj/org/apache/solr/common/SolrDocument.html#getFieldValues(java.lang.String)) or to get a map of all fields: [`getFieldValuesMap()`](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_2_1/solr-solrj/org/apache/solr/common/SolrDocument.html#getFieldValuesMap()) (pay attention to the extra **s**).

Comment: Adding to above:Iterator<SolrDocument> iter = queryResponse.getResults().iterator();

    while (iter.hasNext()) {
      SolrDocument resultDoc = iter.next();

      Collection<Object> content =  resultDoc.getFieldValues("discussions");